# Parse and Switch Elements of Folder Names with Powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, reverse, batch-rename

I have been trying to write a powershell script (my first) to

1. parse out only the folders within a directory
2. select only those folders matching a specific naming convention ('SEASON YEAR')
3. switch the order of the elements of the name ('YEAR SEASON')

I eventually used the program BulkRenameUtility to do this using the regexp ^(\w+) (\d+) and switching the token order to $2 $1 -- however, I still am learning Powershell and would like to be able to do this without using an external program.

So, to re-iterate, at C:\Users\Test

there are folders and files.. some of the folders are named `Spring 2015`, `Fall 2014`, for example. However, other folders have names such as `geogex`. Files have names such as `ENG1A SPRING 2015.odt`and `untitled_0.odt`.

How do I only change the names of the folders named like "Spring 2015" to read "2015 Spring", "2014 Fall" etc. ?

I was able to use

```
 gci | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} | select-string -pattern '\d+'
```

to accomplish 1 and 2 but am stuck on using this to do part 3: actually rename by reversing the elements of the name. I tried putting the above within a variable and  like so:

```
gci | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} | select-string -pattern '\d+' | %{$data = $_.line; Write-Output "$data"};
```

however, while the above outputs exactly the folders I want the array $data seems to only hold the last line of output. Such that:

```
gci | ? {$_.PSIsContainer} | select-string -pattern '\d+' | %{$data = $_.line; Write-Output "$data"};
$data
```

will output:

```
test 123
test 321
test 321
```

I am unsure if this is even the a valid direction to begin with.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So the names of the ones you want to change will _only_ have `season year` and _nothing_ outside of that?

Comment: Right, the names of the folders in question will only have "season year" with no other characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get the job done.

```
$Path = "C:\Users\Test"
$regex = "^(Spring|Summer|Fall|Winter)\s+\d{4}$"

Get-ChildItem $Path | 
    Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -match $regex} | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {$split = $_.Name -split "\s+"; "{0} {1}" -f $split[1],$split[0]}
```

We use that regex to filter out the folder that fit your convention. Should be a little more targeted using specific season names. The year is a little more lacked by just looking for 4 numbers.

Other ways to do it but for the rename I just split the name on the space and reversed the output using the `-f` format operator.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed and a good place to learn from.

Do you have any idea why `%{$data = $_.line; Write-Output "$data"};` outputs only the **last** folder in the list?

Comment: @ElfenDew I cannot think of a reason. Testing locally does yield results for me at least. Worth mentioning that Select-string is for searching string and files and I would not use it for searching folders. something like `-match` like I have done is what you intended.